# How to localize orchard 404 Not Found page

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way to make the 404 Not Found page appear in the language of the user?  The site I am working on supports two languages but this page is always English.  The page comes from Themes//Views/NotFound.cshtml but I don't know how to provide a translated version of this page.  I'm using Orchard 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to localize strings with `T()` method inside `NotFound.cshtml`

```
@T("The page you are looking for does not exist.")
```

Inside **Themes/{ThemeName}/App_Data/Localization/{TargetLocale}/orchard.theme.po**

```
#: "~/Core/Shapes/Views/NotFound.cshtml"
msgctxt "~/Core/Shapes/Views/NotFound.cshtml"
msgid "The page you are looking for does not exist."
msgstr "{Your translation}"
```

Make sure to restart application when you have this. Also you might need to adjust context to target view inside Theme, I'm not sure how exactly that works with theme alternates.

Comment: Thanks!  My page also contains an image with text in it so I want to have an alternate version of this also.  Can I do that?